# How to execute mahout with hadoop installation

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

i'm trying to figure out how to run mahout jar examples with hadoop. I configured mahout and hadoop, now i enter in the hadoop dir and type something like this:

`/Users/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/hadoop jar /Users/hadoop/trunk/examples/mahout-examples-0.5-SNAPSHOT-job.jar org.apache.mahout.SpareVectorsFromSequenceFile -w -i ratings -o ratings_vectors`

but i'm trying and my goal is to run hadoop job for the Grouplens dataset. I executed put command to upload my ratings.dat to Hadoop, and then? The command give me always something like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.SpareVectorsFromSequenceFile
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

My questions are:

- how can i set the right path in hadoop dir to call mahout?
- how can i use the `org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.example.grouplens.GroupLensRecommenderEvaluatorRunner` to compute my data ratings.dat with hadoop?

Thank you very much, I'm beginning with hadoop and mahout ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. They are "sparse vectors", not "spare vectors". See `SpareVectorsFromSequenceFile` which should be `SparseVectorsFromSequenceFile`.